# Exibindo resultados nulos para tabelas relacionadas mysql

Tags: sql, select, join

Estou precisando criar uma query relacional que retorne registros contendo dados tanto da tabela PERMISSAO como da tabela USUARIOS. TODOS os registros da PERMISSAO deverão ser exibidos. Quando não existir registros na USUARIO deve ser exibido NULL. A PERM_USU é usada para relacionar as tabelas USUARIOS e PERMISSAO (no esquema vários para vários). Existe uma condição, onde PERM_USU.USUARIO_ID = 34

permissao

- id (int)
- permissao (varchar)

usuarios

- id (int)
- usuario (varchar)

perm_usu

- permissao_id (int)
- usuario_id (int)

Tentei a query abaixo, porém ela me retorna apenas os registros que existem tanto na tabela1 como na tabela3.

```
select PERMISSAO.*, USUARIOS.* from PERMISSAO
left join PERM_USU on PERMISSAO.ID = PERM_USU.PERMISSAO_ID
left join USUARIOS on USUARIOS.ID = PERM_USU.USUARIO_ID
where PERM_USU.USUARIO_ID = 34
```

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda

Comment: Tentou trocar left join por apenas join?

Comment: Bom testei aqui o que falei acima e não funcionou...

Comment: Tentei trocar o left join por varios outros tipos de join e o resultado foi o mesmo

Comment: Qual banco você está usando?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar *[OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)* (com SQL Server) ou uma subconsulta no *join* (creio que nos demais bancos), algo assim:

Usando *OUTER APPLY*:

```
select
    p.*,
    oau.*
from
    PERMISSAO p
    outer apply(select
                    u.*
                from
                    USUARIOS u
                    inner join PERM_USU pu on (pu.usuario_id = u.id and pu.permissao_id = p.id)
                where
                    u.id = 34) oau
```

Usando subconsulta no *join*:

```
select
    p.*,
    sq.id,
    sq.usuario
from
    PERMISSAO p
    left join ( select
                    pu.permissao_id,
                    u.*
                from
                    USUARIOS u
                    inner join PERM_USU pu on (pu.usuario_id = u.id)
                where
                    u.id = 34) sq on (sq.permissao_id = p.id)
```

Comment: Já tentei essa alternativa, o resultado é o mesmo. Lembro que nem todos os IDs da tabela PERMISSAO estão na tabela PERM_USU, mas preciso que sejam todos exibidos, deixando NULL (ou vazio) para quando não existir

Comment: @MichelCurtiRozatti, realmente estava errado, corrigi minha resposta, veja se agora funcionada. Obs.: na primeira resposta estava sem nenhum banco para testar.